# 'TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index' in TensorFlow Object Detection API

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm currently playing with [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/tensorflow-object-detection-example/blob/master/object_detection_app/app.py) on MacOS and have built a Flask App using the code sample given in the link. I'm using the python version 3.6.4. The app seems to be working fine as GET requests return the code 200. However, when I upload some images to the app to detect objects, it throws the following error.

```
* Serving Flask app "app"
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Feb/2018 11:23:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
/var/folders/f1/k7c234sx5fn9j84yt130_znr0000gn/T/tmpmpi1q72g
[2018-02-14 11:23:52,115] ERROR in app: Exception on /post [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/bkaankuguoglu/Desktop/AccentureRepo/ObjectDetectionRestApi/app.py", line 184, in post
    result = detect_objects(temp.name)
  File "/Users/bkaankuguoglu/Desktop/AccentureRepo/ObjectDetectionRestApi/app.py", line 151, in detect_objects
    for i in range(num_detections):
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Feb/2018 11:23:52] "POST /post HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

The piece of code from which the error is thrown is below, I did pretty much use the code sample with minor changes. As I have read quite a few posts on forums, I came across some comments suggesting `num_detections` on line 151 is a numpy array, therefore, it should be replaced with `num_detections.shape[0]` to iterate over. After trying this, I got an `IndexError: tuple index out of range` error, ending up avoiding a problem by just creating a new one.

```
def detect_objects(image_path):
  image = Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB')
  boxes, scores, classes, num_detections = client.detect(image)

  image.thumbnail((480, 480), Image.ANTIALIAS)

  new_images = {}
  for i in range(num_detections):
    if scores[i] < 0.2: continue
    print(classes[i],scores[i])
    cls = classes[i]
    if cls not in new_images.keys():
      new_images[cls] = image.copy()
    draw_bounding_box_on_image(new_images[cls], boxes[i],
                               thickness=int(scores[i]*10)-4)

  result = {}
  result['original'] = encode_image(image.copy())

  for cls, new_image in new_images.iteritems():
    category = client.category_index[cls]['name']
    result[category] = encode_image(new_image)

  return result
```

So far I've been stuck here and could go no further at the moment. I'd really appreciate any suggestions or comments on this, meanwhile, I'll keep on searching for a solution. If I can be of any help, please feel free to ask me for more details.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this was just an issue regarding python version. When switched to 2.7 from 3.6, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the code from:

```
def detect(self, image):
  ...
  return boxes, scores, classes.astype(int), num_detections
```

to:

```
return boxes, scores, classes.astype(int), num_detections.astype(int)
```

will make a solution.